# Set excluded files using pattern or wildcard in PyCharm (remote host)

Tags: deployment, pycharm

I use `PyCharm` to deploy and upload changes on my VPS. This project isn't on Git so I can't use .gitignore.

I find `excluded paths` in `PyCharm` deployment configuration very handy but I can't figure out if and how  can I use wildcards to let pycharm know which files I want to exclude.

For example, I want not to upload `*.pyc` files. For now, I would have to specify paths for all `*.pyc` files.

[image]

Is it possible? I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to exclude folders from upload/download:

1. Explicitly, by marking the corresponding paths as excluded in the Remote Host tool window, or in the Excluded Paths tab of the Deployment dialog box.

   In the Remote Host tool window, you can exclude both entire folders and specific files.
2. By name, that is, by specifying patterns that determine the names of files and folders to be excluded in the Exclude Items by Name text box of the Options dialog box.

Separate files can be protected against upload/download only through excluding them by name.

## Excluding files and folders from upload/download by name

Open the Options dialog box by doing one of the following:

- On the main menu, choose Tools | Deployment | Options.
- Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S or by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or PyCharm | Preferences for macOS. Expand the Build, Execution, Deployment node, and then click Options under Deployment.

In the Options dialog box that opens, specify the patterns that define the names of these files and folders in the Exclude items by name text box. Use semicolons as delimiters. Wildcards are welcome.

The exclusion is applied recursively. This means that if a matching folder has subfolders, the contents of these subfolders are not deployed either.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.3/options.html

Comment: "Wildcards are welcome," so the answer says, and so the jetbrains documentation says. But when I use `file*.out` or `file*` or `file.*` or even just `file`, and run Deployment > Sync With Deployed, all the `file*.out` files are still included. So a working example of exclusion with wildcard would be lovely.

Comment: The link above is for pycharm 2017. The [current version 2019](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deployment-excluded-paths-tab.html) says nothing about wildcards, and only mentions excluding folders. It seems like they changed it....